# Show that $u(t) \leq u(a) e^{\int_a^t f(s) ds}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let u(t) be a continuously differentiable function on [a,b] and the following inequality holds $\forall t \in [a,b]$ such that $u'(t) \leq f(t)u(t).$
Show that
$u(t) \leq u(a) e^{\int_a^t f(s) ds}$

I have been just staring at this problem for a while and dont know where to start.
I have done basis rearranging, but cannot make any real progress.
Does anyone have any hints as to where to start, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: pretend you're solving the differential equation $u' = f \cdot u$ by separation of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Gronwall Inequality, but let's use [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method):

Maybe we can discretize

$$ u'(t) \approx  \frac{u(t+\Delta t) - u(t) }{\Delta t} \leq  f(t) u(t) $$

then get:

$$ u(t+\Delta t) \leq u(t) \left( 1 +  f(t) \Delta t \right)$$

By induction and using $1 + x \approx e^x$ for $x << 1$:

$$ u(t+ n\Delta t) \leq u(t) \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 +  f(t + k \Delta t) \Delta t \right) \approx  u(t)  e^{\sum_{k=1}^n f(t + k \Delta t) \Delta t} $$

And taking the scaling limit, $\Delta t \to 0$.

$$ u(t+a) \leq u(t) e^{\int_0^a f(t) dt}$$

---

**Historical note**:  Gronwall's inequality result was proven by [Richard Bellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Bellman), father of Dynamic Programming and coiner of the "Curse of Dimensionality".

Answer (score 4):

Set $g(t)=u(t)e^{-\int_a^tf(s)ds}$ 
$g'(t)=u'(t)e^{-\int_a^tf(s)ds}-u(t)f(t)e^{-\int_a^tf(s)ds}\leq 0$, hence $g$ is a decreasing function then $g(t)\leq g(a) $.

Answer (score 2):

This is the well known *[Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) .* A very rigorous proof can be found from Tao's book, *nonlinear dispersive equations*, Chapter 1. You should be able to derive it yourself as well. Note a naive separation of variables would not work, as $f$'s sign is undetermined.